# get content of author page

Tags: post-content

is there a (reliable) way to get the content of an author page ?

I need to get the list of the shortcodes on the page, actually, so i wanted to use get_shortcode_tags_in_content(), but for that i need the content, and don't find a way.

- `global $post; $post->post_content;` does not work ($post is not instance of WP_Post)
- `get_queried_object()->post_content;` does not work (instance of WP_User, not WP_Post)
- `add_filter('the_content','callback')` is not triggered

I don't know how to do that, author pages seems to be really special. This one is created with divi theme builder, so maybe I should use a solution specific to divi ? But I'd rather find a solution that works everywhere.